# Is there a standard XDG location for user secrets?

Tags: ssh, xdg, xdg-user-dirs, openpgp

XDG defines `~/.config`, `~/.cache` and other shell-agnostic locations for user configuration files. Some applications define their own locations for user secrets, like `~/.ssh` and `~/.gpg`.

Is there an XDG-defined location for user secrets? For example, `~/.secret`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought that the XDG spec intended that you store secrets using the [secret-storage-spec](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/secret-storage-spec/).

> The Secrets API allows client applications to store secrets securely using a service running in the user's login session.

This is where [GNOME Keyring](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GnomeKeyring) and others come into play, being the backend that manages the actual secrets.

#### GNOME Keyring

[image: ss1]